# DCA Pulse service not functioning properly (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)

Tags: services

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and installed DCA Pulse to share printer counters with my printer vendor. The service is called dcapulse.service and connects properly with the web service of my vendor.

After installing everything works fine, but after a reboot of Ubuntu it doesn't work fine anymore. After the reboot:

- the service is enabled ('systemctl list-unit-files | grep dca' shows enabled / enabled)
- the service seems to be connected correctly with the web service of my vendor (Connection: Connected to https://...etc etc)
- however, the service doesn't monitor my printer (Devices Monitored: 0)

What could be the reason everything works fine after (re)installing the DCA Pulse service and doesn't work fine anymore after a reboot of my Ubuntu device?

Thanks in advance!

SJW

Comment: PS in the meantime I found out I have to disable my hardware firewall for a few minutes, even after the reinstall I mentioned. It looks as if a onetime handshake is required after a reinstall and after a reboot. Does this make sense or should it only be necessary after the install?